# Fetch id for viewpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

**FIXED**
 what i want to do is a viewpage that contains accountslist by clicking on any of account name it should open selected accountid Payablerecords and Reciveablerecords. Note:Payables and Receivables are two Propertiest Taken From same DataModel tbl_Transaction(Which is collection).So can i get Id for collections?

I am getting the Selected AccountID records in Payable view but I cant get the same id related record in Reciveable view plz help me out.
Here is the code.

```
     public class AccountsController : Controller
    {
        private AccountBs objBs;
        public AccountsController() 
        {
            objBs = new AccountBs();
        }
        // GET: Shinwari/Accounts
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var accounts = objBs.GetALL();
            return View(accounts);
        }

    <%=@model IEnumerable<BOL.tbl_Accounts>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Accounts</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Discription)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Index", "AccountDetailPayable", new {accountid=item.AId },null)
                @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)*@
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Discription)
            </td>
    }
</table>%>
```

### ReciveableAndPayablecontroller

```
private TransictionBs objbs;
public Details() 
{
    objbs = new TransictionBs();
}
// GET: Shinwari/AccountDetails
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int accountid)
{
    ADetailsVm v = new ADetailsVm();
    //Load both the collection properties
    v.Payables = objbs.GetALL().Where(p => p.AId == accountid && p.tbl_TransictionType.Type.Contains("Payable")).ToList();
    v.Reciveables = objbs.GetALL().Where(r => r.AId==accountid && r.tbl_TransictionType.Type.Contains("Reciveable")).ToList();

    return View(v);
```

### Veiw

```
@model BOL1.ADetailsVm
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>AccountDetails</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table id="Payables" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Discription
        </th>
        <th>
            Amount
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Payables)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Date
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.TDiscription
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Amount
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

**Note Payable and reciveable both views are identical **

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. The code you have shown would not _get the required result_ because because it does not set a route value for the `id` (you would need a 5th parameter of `null`)

Comment: check it now i hope u will get it

Comment: Now how can i get the same id in Recivable controller and viewpage ?

Comment: The same way your doing it above. If its not working, then you need to show your actual code (not some generic example that works). No one can guess what mistakes you may have made.

Comment: Check it now @Stephen Muecke

Comment: Sorry, but I till do not understand what your problem is. Are you saying you cannot hit the `Index()` method and/or get the value its `id` attribute. you have not even shown the `ActionLink()` method that redirects to that method.

Comment: If you want a link to it in the view you have shown, then it would need to be `@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Index", "AccountDetailReciveable", new { id=item.AId }, null)`

Comment: i have already given the Actionlink to AccountDetailPayable i can not give 2nd link to it what i want is to get the same id

Comment: Your not making sense and I have no idea what you want.

Comment: In Accounts View  ActionLink i am giving the controllerName (AccountDetailPayable) where it will navigate Now from AccountDetailPayable View I want to navigate to AccountDetailReciveable.

Comment: Then see my previous comment - its `@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Index", "AccountDetailReciveable", new { id=item.AId }, null)`

Comment: this is what i am unable to do @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Index", "AccountDetailReciveable", new { id=item.AId }, null)  and i also tried @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Index", "AccountDetailReciveable", new { id=Model.AId }, null) 
it says the current context is not defined.

Comment: In which view are you doing this? (it works if you use it in the view you have shown). If your referring to some other view, then show it!

Comment: Kindly check now i have pasted view code This is the 2nd day i am trying to solve it but i cant

Comment: The 2 action links at the top of your `Reciveable` view make no sense. The model is a collection, not a single item so how could you pass the ID (a collection does not contain a property for an ID). Its impossible to understand what your trying to do.

Comment: so what approach i should use to get selected AccountId Records ?

Comment: Don't edit the answer into your question. Please roll back the edit and post your answer as an actual answer to your question.

Comment: I can not answer and this is for others to help

Comment: No need of all codes just share the main parts for understanding we dont need to see your full code to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create new class where you need to add two lists as following.

```
           public NewClass
{
List<tbl_Transiction>Payables{get;set;}
List<tbl_Transiction>Reciveables{get;set;}
}
```

and Add the class to your DbContext Class as follows.

```
public DbSet<NewClass>PayablesAndReceiveables{get;set;}
```

And loop your newly created lists objects in View where you need them.

Comment: you are very late but your answer is absolutely right.

Comment: SOrry for late Answer I just saw your questions so I thought my answer might help others.

Answer (score 0):

TO have same table work like 2 different properties you need to create new model class, In my case it is as following..

```
    public ADetailsVm
{
List<tbl_Transiction>Payables{get;set;}
List<tbl_Transiction>Reciveables{get;set;}
}
```

And then  add the following class to DBContext Class ... it would be like

```
public DbSet<ADetailsVm>ADetailsVm{get;set;}
```